# I keep receiving this runtime error after I decide to read a file using a do loop, what could be the issue?

Tags: fortran, gfortran

For some reason I keep receiving this error:

```
Please enter your name
Gene
 please enter a number BETWEEN 0 and 1000
10
           1           3           5           7           9
At line 27 of file practice.f90 (unit = 2, file = 'practice2.txt')
Fortran runtime error: End of file

Error termination. Backtrace:
#0  0x10ae39ebd
#1  0x10ae3ab75
#2  0x10ae3b76b
#3  0x10b069a13
#4  0x10b062d36
#5  0x10b063bd2
#6  0x10b0693c9
#7  0x10ae26a61
#8  0x10ae26c58
```

This is my code:

```
program practice
implicit none
character(len=56):: nom
integer,allocatable:: j(:)
integer:: i,num,n,k

write(*,*) 'Please enter your name'
read(*,*) nom
write(*,*) 'please enter a number BETWEEN 0 and 1000'
read(*,*) num

open(2,file='practice2.txt')

n=0
do i=1,num
    if (mod(i,2)/=0) then
    n=n+1
    write(2,*) i
    end if 
end do

allocate(j(n))
rewind(2)

do k=1,n
    read(2,*) j(1:n)
    write(*,*) j(1:n)
end do 

close(2)

deallocate(j)
end program practice
```

My program is meant to print only the odd numbers from 0 to the number chosen by the user, then allocate an array based on the numbers. Afterwards I will compute the sum (I have not gotten to this part yet.)

I'm not sure what the issue is, as everything seems to be working accordingly, it is only after my last do loop that there appears to be an issue.

Thank you,
Gene.

Comment: You're reading `j(1:n)` items from a file `k=1,n` times, where the file only has `n` items.

Comment: i don't understand, if the file has n items, shouldn't it be able to read the file from the top until the nth item?

Comment: `read(2,*) j(1:n)` is reading `n` items.  This statement occurs inside a do-loop  `k=1,n`, so you are doing `n` reads from the file, ie., it expects `n*n` items in the file.  Either remove the `do k=1,n` loop or change to `read(2,*) j(k)`.

Comment: I suspect that this can be fixed by changing the working variable in the second loop to 'k' instead of n. A second issue may be that the colon in the array part is causing the program to expect multiple entries. If you want to access only a single entry in the array, the correct code is _j(k)_

Comment: Awesome, that solved my issue. Thanks you guys!!!